# Print out text with dynamic pieces in Python to the Terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python how could I accomplish printing out the time in realtime in a Terminal?

```
while(True):
    print("[ " + "Time: " + datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + " ]")
```

The code above will just print out the line infinite amount of times. How can I do a "static" line of text and refresh the time every second without doing print statements on every line? Hope this wasn't too confusing :)

Wasn't sure what to search for, it didn't give me the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `print` outputs `\n` (or `\r\n` on Windows) at the end of the line to move to the **N**ew line. You just need to output `\r` instead in order to **R**eturn to the beginning of the current line (and sleep for a second before outputting again at the same line):

```
import time, datetime
while True:
    s = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('[ Time: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S ]')
    print(s, end='\r')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import datetime

while(True):
    sys.stdout.write("\r" + "[ " + "Time: " + datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + " ]")    
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

You can try this library